# Full JSON Isn't Receiving on Django REST Framework Registration

Tags: json, django, post

I have a Django REST Registration page with two additional boxes (`first_name` and `last_name`). The registration page works fine when I use the input boxes but when I try to do a POST to the Register page, I constantly get that the form is invalid. Upon inspection, it looks like only the `first_name` and `last_name` are in the `cleaned_data`, but the JSON I am posting through Postman looks like:

`{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "test",
    "password1": "testtest",
    "password2": "testtest"
}`

and it's not just Postman, I have also been trying the same thing in an Android app via Volley. I can't figure out why some of the JSON isn't going through.

Here is my **views.py** for the Register page:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, models
from userauth.templates.registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from django.http import *

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'userauth/index.html')

@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print(form.data)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form valid')
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)

            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

            responseData = {
                'token': str(token),
            }

            return JsonResponse(responseData)
        else:
            print('form not valid')
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            raise Http404
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

and here is my **forms.py** for the page where it's supposed to add the extra blanks:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Another weird thing... Sometimes, the Register page will work on Postman if I use their built in formatter:
[image: Postman formatter]
but not when I'm using raw JSON:
[image: Postman raw]

Am I just formatting the JSON wrong? How does Postman format their POST requests? Any help is appreciated... Thanks

Comment: You're not using DRF. You're using plain Django. You haven't done anything to accept JSON, only form-encoded data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman actually, what makes you say that? Because another page of mine works with posting a JSON to it (The DRF login page)

Comment: Well that's a DRF page. But the view you have shown here is not. It's a standard Django view, it doesn't use the DRF `api_page` decorator or use any of its class-based views, it uses `request.POST` instead of `request.data` ... it's not a DRF page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay, thanks

Comment: you may use form_data=json.loads(request.body) and get data

Comment: @PavanKumarTS is that all I need to do? I get more errors after I change that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want to move to DRF you may try altering existing code as below

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data=json.loads(request.body) 
        form = RegistrationForm(data=form_data)
        print(form.data)
        if form.is_valid():
          pass
```

Comment: This worked great for accepting JSON. Thanks. One other question, is there an advantage to moving it to DRF?

Comment: @EthanShoe if your application is more dependent on JSON data you can go for DRF which will drastically reduce your lines of code.